# Save changes to object from listview when returning to parent activity

Tags: android

Sorry for the vague title. But my problem is this:

I'm using Intent to pass the position from a listview from my parent activity to a DetailActivity where i create the object. I fill some edittexts with this information. When I return to the parent activity I want any changes made to be saved to the object. How do I do go about handling this?

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public static final String POSITION = "POSITION";

    private static final int REQUEST_CODE = 1111;

    private ListView lv_contacts;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ContactListAdapter adapter = new ContactListAdapter(this, R.layout.list_item, ContactList.getInstance().getContacts());
        lv_contacts = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv_contacts);
        lv_contacts.setAdapter(adapter);
        lv_contacts.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DetailActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra(POSITION, position);
                startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

**DetailActivity**

```
public class DetailActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private TextView first_name, last_name;
    private EditText phone_number, location;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail);

        int position = getIntent().getIntExtra(MainActivity.POSITION, -1);
        Contact contact = ContactList.getInstance().getContact(position);

        first_name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_first_name);
        last_name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_last_name);
        phone_number = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_phone_number);
        location = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_location);

        first_name.setText(contact.getFirst_name());
        last_name.setText(contact.getLast_name());
        phone_number.setHint(contact.getPhonenumber());
        location.setHint(contact.getLocation());
    }
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: You could save the data in SQLite

Answer (score 0):

You already have the object ContactList as a singleton which should make this easy. If you are using the ContactList for the listView adapter to use all you have to do is determine how the previous activity ended, like if any contact was modified. If so, just call the listview adapter's notifydatasetchanged on the activity's onActivityResult.